# Model name is displaying on top of view

Tags: model-view-controller, view, model

I do not know y but the model class name and namespace is being displayed in the view automatically.Below is my Output

```
MVC_Rocks.ViewModel.EmployeeViewModel MVC_Rocks.Models.EmployeeViewModel

Hello sainathsurender
```

and below is the code in my view

> @{
>       Layout = null; } @Model MVC_Rocks.Models.EmployeeViewModel
>
> ViewModel
>
> ## Hello @Model.UserName

Tried using

> @using MVC_Rocks.Models; 
>   @Model EmployeeViewModel

Can anyone suggest where I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the keyword model in lowercase when defining it for the page. And use an upper case M when accessing it.

```
@model EmployeeViewModel

Hello @Model.Username
```